# Aggregated Data vs RESTful Resources for AngularJs SPA

Tags: angularjs, rest, aggregation

I am working on a single page app using **AngularJs Framework**.
The website is kind of social networking and thus consists of various *kinds of data* to be fetched from server.
Will it be good to be RESTful and make each entity a **'resource'** or implement other way to get **'aggregated JSON'** response, since RESTful results in too many calls ?

If non-RESTful approach is used, ( say by using `$http` service ), then how can I still maintain the modular architecture of app.

Consider example for clarification:

let the server return:

```
{  
  user: {  
         name: ....  
               ....,  
         projects: [{  
                     ....
                     ....  
         }],  
         ...  
  }  
}
```

How can I create modules such as `User` and `Projects`, each with its own functions and logically separate and independent.
Its almost similar to making single `$http` request and distributing response to many **services.**
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I love SPAs.  I wish I was doing this with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer - I am by no means a REST expert or purist

This is a very good question and something I struggled with as well. I just couldn't justify having X number of REST calls to display a single form/page, where X could sometimes be fairly large. The solution I ended up with which seems to work reasonably well in my case was a hybrid approach. I use aggregates (View Models) to render the forms/pages, these View Models I get from the server with a single API call. For create/update/delete operations I extract the actual resource from the View Model on the client and post that using a more RESTful approach.

This gives me best of both worlds, low number of API calls to display page, RESTful approach on post which reduces network overhead.

In addition to the above I use an approach I saw on [breeze.js](http://www.breezejs.com/) documentation which seems to work really great as well, on application startup I load all commonly used static lookup data (typically data used for dropdowns/select lists) in a single LookupsAggregate and cache that on the clients. This model is then available from the start and no need to refetch them everytime you need to display a dropdown/select lists.